# error while fetching the pb format of config file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[image]

I'm using Hyperledger fabric 1.1 version, working on fabric-sample/first-network. When trying to fetch the config.pb file inside the cli container i'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

What was the exact command you ran to produce that error?

Fabric-sample/first-network uses TLS by default and the first line in your screenshot has [grpc] which makes me think you aren't running the command with TLS enabled.

Try this command to get the latest config.

```
peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

Where $CHANNEL_NAME is your channel name and $ORDERER_CA is the path to your orderers certificate in the CLI container. e.g. `ORDERER_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem`

There is also an example of fetching the config block for fabric-samples/first-network. It can be found under **fabric-samples/first-network/scripts/utils.sh** in the **fetchChannelConfig() function (line 211 and line 215)**. One of those should work as it was written for that setup.